# Async.waterfall not going to next function

Tags: node.js, callback

I am new to node and callbacks.  Right now I am using async.waterfall to mess with videos but for some reason the process exits after I inserted the second function, 'pipe,' in my waterfall.  Am I not calling it correctly?

```
// Download the video from S3, get thumbnail, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
        async.waterfall([
            function download(next) {
                // Download the video from S3 into a buffer.
                s3.getObject({
                        Bucket: srcBucket,
                        Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
            },
            function pipe(next) {
                // Download the video from S3 into a buffer.
                console.log("pipe function started");
                var params = {Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey};
                s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file, next);
            },
            function upload(response, next) {
                console.log("upload function started");
                // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
                s3.putObject({
                        Bucket: dstBucket,
                        Key: dstKey,
                        Body: response.Body,
                        ContentType: response.ContentType
                    },
                    next);
            }
            ], function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(
                        'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                        ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
                        ' due to an error: ' + err
                    );
                } else {
                    console.log(
                        'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                        ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
                    );
                }

                callback(null, "message");
            }


        );
```

Comment: Does `.pipe` take a callback? I'd expect you have to register `next` as the handler for the readable stream's `end` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

You said you inserted the `pipe` function. So, originally, the `upload(response, next)` function was called after the `download` function. Given the signature of the `upload` function, we can surmise that the `download` function is calling its `next` function roughly this way: `next(null, response)`. Therefore, any function right after the `download` function in the waterfall array will be passed 2 arguments: `(response, next)`.

See the documentation for [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) for more info on how data is passed between tasks.

So, the immediate problem with your code is that `pipe()` is actually being passed 2 arguments: `(response, next)`, but your code only defines one argument: `(next)`. Therefore, it is attempting to use the `response` argument (an object) as if it is a function.

*You also have other issues, but how to fix them depends on what you are trying to achieve.*

Comment: Where am I passing 'response' to 'pipe'?